# How to install MeteorJS on a IBMi / AS400

Tags: node.js, curl, meteor, ibm-midrange

I would like to know if it is possible to install MeteorJS on an AS400 (IBMi),
as it's able to run Node.js, MongoDB, ...

I quickly tested the installation via "curl", but I have a message saying that the platform is not supported.

Would anyone have already tested via the NPM packages?

Where I have a doubt: is all Meteor code in JS, or is there a binary layer that makes it impossible?

Comment: Is it for development or production?

Comment: The 2... My company sell an ERP running on AS400... We are looking for a new web architecture based on Node.js, because it could run on the AS400 or beside, on another server. Meteor seems interesting, and I'm discovering it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once built (i.e. used for production), Meteor is just like any other Node.js app.

Therefore it should be able to run on your system, provided that the latter can run the required Node.js version (and MongoDB if you run it from your system as well) and it has the native bindings for dependent packages / modules.

During development, Meteor relies on a number of extra [scripts](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/scripts), typically to watch files and bundle (i.e. build) the Node.js app. This is where you might not be able to use Meteor on your system. For Linux and macOS, it uses shell scripts. For Windows, it uses an executable.

While not ideal, you could still perform your development on an officially supported platform, then from time to time build your app and run it on your system to check that the Node.js app runs everywhere as advertised.

Comment: Ok, thanks ghybs... I'll verify if theses scripts run in a AS400 / PASE environnement ( it's an Unix/Aix  sub system)...

Comment: I would check first that it works for a production app, especially to make sure that Meteor core packages have native bindings for your architecture.